How to deform a Bezier curve without breaking the array
I have an array modifier and a curve modifier to make my brick wall go in a circular pattern.
I want to be able to manipulate the Bezier curve without breaking the array. When I start dragging left or right, or any direction, the pattern starts to break up, leaving gaps, or squashing into array pattern.
Id like to keep the fixed count to 84, without needed to increase the count, to fix up the gap.
Because If I keep on manipulating the Bezier curve, it causes different measurements of the gap, then I have to increase or decrease the Fixed Count each time.
So is there a way to close off (Lock) the array, and modify the Bezier curve?

Examples.




Well, how do you want it to work? You can either set it to a certain number of bricks or fit a defined length or fit the curve. While manipulating the curve you change its length - so Fixed Length cannot work, Fixed Count cannot work either, because a specific number of bricks have a specific length which is a similar problem as the Fixed Length and changes the count. Fit Curve would change the brick count as well which you do not want (and not be perfect either because it can result in overlapping bricks). So maybe you need to tell us what you want: rubber bricks that stretch to fit?

Thanks for insight, I tried the option in the array modifier, Fit Curve, at first there was a small overlap, but playing with the Relative offset Z Factor, it fixed the distance. I can now manipulate the Bezier curve to any direction and the array pattern remains as a Möbius strip.
https://ibb.co/wQKHdZS

Okay, of course you can always manipulate all settings manually until it matches. Your question sounded as if you wanted it to be matching dynamically to all changes you make on the the curve. That's why I voted to close the question as "Needs details or clarity"... because the answer: "adjust the values so that it fits" seemed too simple for me.
